# How to get value from resolved jQuery.Deferred()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-deferred

Here is my basic situation:

```
function somePostThing() {
  return $post("/someUrl").done(doSomething);
}

function doSomething(data) {
  // do stuff with the data
}

var object = {};
object.deferred = somePostThing();

// A few cycles later, object.deferred may be resolved or unresolved
object.deferred.done(function () { /* ... */ });
```

The last line may or may not work, because `done` won't fire in the event that the deferred object is already resolved. I would like to be able to do something like this:

```
function doSomethingWithData(data) {
  // do stuff
}

var value;
if (object.deferred.isResolved()) doSomethingWithData(object.deferred.value());
else object.deferred.done(doSomethingWithData);
```

How do I get the value of an already resolved `jQuery.Deferred()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, that's actually exactly why the whole "Deferred" mechanism came into being.  If you pass in a "done" function after the asynchronous process has been resolved, it most definitely will be executed immediately.

From the jQuery API docs:

> If more functions are added by deferred.then() after the Deferred is resolved, they are called immediately with the arguments previously provided.

That's true for the ".done()" functions also.

Comment: This is definitely the correct answer, but I'll leave my answer - I think it's useful for people to know that things don't happen to objects when you're not looking :)

Comment: Thanks for your prompt (and accurate, no less) answer.

Comment: It may also be prudent to note that there potentially multiple 'return values', depending on the promise method you attach your handler with, and the chain which executes before it. see the jQuery docs for the differences between `.done(doneHandler)` & `.then(thenHandler)`. Basically, values returned from `doneHandler` will disappear, but anything returned from `thenHandler` will be piped to the next-registered handler.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript in a browser is single threaded. So, in the following code snippet:

```
object.deferred = somePostThing();

// Nothing can happen to object.deferred here

object.deferred.done(function () { /* ... */ });
```

nothing will happen in between the first line and the last line. "A few cycles later" doesn't mean anything in JavaScript-land. Something will only happen to  `object.deferred` after the function that is executing returns.

Comment: This is certainly true, but I interpreted (perhaps too liberally) "some cycles later" as meaning, "some event loops later".

Comment: @Pointy You could be right - I was interpreting the code as written :)

Comment: Yeah, I should have put the "some cycles later" part inside of a call to `setTimeout` to be clear that it wasn't going to be evaluated right away.